# How to Apply a Coupon to a Stripe Customer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, stripe.net

I can't find any way to apply the coupon/discount to an existing customer who has a reoccurring payment. I'm using the `stripe` gem. I went ahead and created the coupon on the Stripe dashboard. I see no mention on how to add a coupon on their API page. I've tried this solution below but to no avail.

```
cu = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("cus_XXX")

cu.discount = "my_coupon_id"

cu.save

# returns Stripe::InvalidRequestError: (Status 400) Received unknown parameter: discount
```

There must be some sort of method I'm missing. What am I missing to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that customer id was fake though. :p

Comment: Oh my bad, assumed the worst! I guess it's not really secret anyway but seemed better to remove it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `coupon` parameter along with the [Update Customer API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#update_customer) so in Ruby that would be something like this:

```
cu = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("cus_XXX")
cu.coupon = "my_coupon_id"
cu.save
```